# How to change the size of custom map in Xamarin.form?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on this sample [Click here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin/)

I find out the map displays with App.ScreenWidth and App.ScreenHeight. Here is my the xaml code below:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <local:CustomMap x:Name="customMap" MapType="Street" 
        WidthRequest="{x:Static local:App.ScreenWidth}" 
        HeightRequest="{x:Static local:App.ScreenHeight}" />
</ContentPage.Content>
```

How can I set the App.screenheight to 1/2 of its height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most convienient might be to use an `AbsoluteLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. I'll show use how to do it with an `AbsoluteLayout`, since this is what I've used more often

```
<ContentPage.Content>
  <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
    <local:CustomMap [...]
      AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
      AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,.5" />
  </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

With `VerticalOptions="Fill"` and `HorizontalOptions=Fill` you tell the `AbsoluteLayout` to take the whole available space in your `ContentPage`. The `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"` is an attached property that tells your `CustomMap` that the positioning in the `AbsoluteLayout` should be relative. At the end you are telling your `CustomMap` that it should be positioned at (0,0) taking the while width and the half height with `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,.5"`.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like the map to cover half of your app screen, just use a `Grid` system.

The code would look like this:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>            
        <local:CustomMap x:Name="customMap" MapType="Street" Grid.Row="0" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

So by adding 2 rows to your Grid with each equal height will guaranty that the screen is divided in half and by placing the map in the first row will keep its height also to half of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot do calculation in XAML so you can use the code-behind method.

Below is the example code with some simple calculation:

```
 public class MapPageCS : ContentPage
    {
      public MapPageCS ()
      {
        var customMap = new CustomMap {
          MapType = MapType.Street,
          WidthRequest = App.ScreenWidth /2,
          HeightRequest = App.ScreenHeight/2
        };
        ...

        Content = customMap;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
customMap.WidthRequest = Application.Current.MainPage.Width;
customMap.HeightRequest = Application.Current.MainPage.Height / 2;
```

If you want to change the Map height dynamically in the code behind file, fx. in my case when a bottom sheet opens and closes, you must reset the width as well for it to resize on iOS.